# Karate: Compare pdf response file

Tags: karate

I have an api which is returning pdf file as response. Is there a way to compare pdf files in Karate?

Is there any way to fetch the Title parameter and compare with another pdf?

Answer (score 0):

No, only binary comparisons are possible.

That said, you may be able to integrate a Java lib that does this via Java interop.

Comment: Ok Thank you Peter. I will try that